# UnMarshalling with Unique value using JaxB

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have xml returned like,

```
<UniequeTestList>
 <UniequeTest>
  <FirstName>a</FirstName>
  <LastName>b</LastName>
 </UniequeTest>
 <UniequeTest>
  <FirstName>a</FirstName>
  <LastName>b</LastName>
 </UniequeTest>
</UniequeTestList>
```

I unmarshal it using JaxB in `List<UniequeTest>`. 
And obviously that list must have mulitple object which are same.
Can I make it unieque at the same time I unmarshall it?

I can't use HashSet or LinkedHashSet to make it unieque at same time. I mean what I want in Unmarshall list is unieque object if value under that object is same.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "make it unique"?

Comment: JAXB is for converting your XML data into Java classes as it is defined. If you require the "data" in the file to be altered (e.g. made unique) you should either manipulate it with an XSLT before hand, or just process the data in your Java objects once JAXB has populated them into a Collection.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan  I mean what I want in Unmarshall list is unieque object if value under that object is same.

Answer (score 3):

You can eventually use a listener to the JAXB Unmarshaller:

```
 class JAXBUnmarshallingListener extends Unmarshaller.Listener {

   @Override
   public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
   }

   @Override
   public void afterUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
   }
 }
```

In the callback method, you can implement a simple cache and replace the object newly created by JAXB by your own unique instance (the new JAXB instance will be garbage collected afterwards as no one keeps referencing it. Note this method won't save you the cost of the instantiation and the gc of these objects.).